# How to add SwiftLint to Swift Vapor project

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, vapor, swiftlint

I'm trying to add [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint) to my Swift Vapor project but had no luck figuring out these errors.

[image]

Full Package.swift code:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "VaporApp",
    platforms: [
       .macOS(.v10_15)
    ],
    dependencies: [
        //  A server-side Swift web framework.
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", from: "4.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint.git", from: "0.50.3")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "App",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "Vapor", package: "vapor")
            ],
            swiftSettings: [
                .unsafeFlags(["-cross-module-optimization"], .when(configuration: .release))
            ],
            plugins: [.plugin(name: "SwiftLintPlugin", package: "SwiftLint")]
        ),
        .target(name: "Run", dependencies: [.target(name: "App")]),
        .testTarget(name: "AppTests", dependencies: [
            .target(name: "App"),
            .product(name: "XCTVapor", package: "vapor"),
        ])
    ]
)
```

**Update:**
Above errors were fixed after setting swift-tools-version to ^5.6
`// swift-tools-version:5.6`

But now having another issue. I have tried resetting package caches and upgrading packages.
[image]

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? They explain how to install it very clearly. [Xcode](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint#xcode) SwiftLint setup

Comment: Yes, I was following the instructions in 'Swift Package' section.

Comment: First of all, the correct name is `.plugin(name: "SwiftLintPlugin", package: "SwiftLint")`. As soon as you add that try to save the file and build and see if the error persists

Comment: Doesn't work, same error.

Comment: Please post your entire Package.swift file so we can reproduce the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your tools version in the Package.swift file to at least 5.6

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. But now I'm having another issue:

Comment: Failed to resolve dependencies Dependencies could not be resolved because root depends on 'swiftlint' 0.50.3..<1.0.0.
'swiftlint' >= 0.50.3 cannot be used because no versions of 'swiftlint' match the requirement 0.50.4..<1.0.0 and package 'swiftlint' is required using a stable-version but 'swiftlint' depends on an unstable-version package 'swift-syntax'.

Comment: Thanks! But now I have another issue...

Comment: Try running `swift package update`

Comment: Tried, didn't work.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is deleting the Package.resolved then and maybe the SwiftPM cache

Comment: Somehow I fixed this issue by using ```package(url: "https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint", branch: "main")```